# How to ignore all notifications from an observable sequence except errors?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I am looking to create an observable that subscribes to an input source but then only keeps the error message (i.e. ignores elements and completion messages until someone calls Dispose).

Basically I am looking for something like [Observable.IgnoreElements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229242%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) but that would work more like [Observable.Never](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211979%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

The problem is that IgnoreElements leaves both termination messages (success and error). I only want to leave the error notification and ignore when a sequence successfully terminates. The Never method does this, but only generates an observable sequence, you cannot create it from another sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is to ignore all updates except for a **single** exception, if it occurs, then you can do this:

```
public static IObservable<T> OnlyError<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(
        observer => source.Subscribe(
            value => { },
            observer.OnError));
}
```

<sub>(The rest of the answer is no longer relevant because the question was changed.)</sub>

If you want to have **multiple** exceptions in a single sequence, the solution is a little more involved.

The implicit contract for `IObserver<T>` is that it will be called according to this pattern:

```
OnNext* [OnError|OnCompleted]
```

That is, `OnError` can be called at most once, and it ends the sequence. See the following excerpt from [Observer Design Pattern Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519622(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Once the provider calls the `OnError` or `IObserver<T>.OnCompleted` method, there should be no further notifications, . . .

If you want to have a sequence that can have multiple "errors," define something like this:

```
interface ITry<T>
{
    bool HasValue { get; }
    T Value { get; }
    Exception Error { get; }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
IObservable<ITry<T>>
```

Keep `IObserver<T>.OnError(Exception)` meaning something went wrong *with the sequence itself*, not with the items in the sequence.

Comment: Sorry, I probably was not clear in my question. I don't need multiple errors, I just need any error to be broadcasted as per the normal grammar. I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there is an obvious solution... simply concatenate to Never, like this:

```
IObservable<TSource> Never<TSource>(IObservable<TSource> source)
{
    return source.IgnoreElements().Concat(Observable.Never<TSource>());
}
```

Comment: although Timothy's method is more "resource efficient" (makes less objects)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question then I think this will work.

given an observable named `source`:

```
source.Materialize().Where(x => x.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError);
```